# Regex to find evaluate number pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match on a specific given number pattern.

The patterns are:

`123456`
`1234XX`
`1234*`

Not allowed are:
A combinations like: `1234*X` or `1234X*`
Or a multiple `*`: `1234**`

I already tried this expression:

```
/^[\\+\\#\\*0-9]{0,25}[X]*$/
```

But here I got the multiple `*` and `1234*X` as valid expressions.

Does anyone have an idea of a proper soultion or a way to a solution?

**Edit:** 
Ok, I think I should clearify the rules.

The regex should match any given number:

```
012345
+12345
#1234525
```

But also match for strings with a `X` in it.

```
12345X
12345XX
1234XXXXXX
XXXXXX
```

The `X`s should always stand on the end of the string.

A single `*` should only be allowed at the end of the string.

```
1234*
1234556*
1*
```

Multiple `*` aren't allowed. Only one `*` at the end of the string.

The combination of `X` and `*` are not allowed. `1234X*` or `12345*X` are not allowed.

Length restriction: 0 to 25 characters.

Comment: Like this `^\d{4}..?$`?

Comment: You can use: ^\d{6}|\d{4}X{2}|\d{4}\\*$

Comment: Try `'~^(?=.{0,25}$)\d+[X*]*$~'`, or [`'~^(?=.{0,25}$)\d+[X*]{2}$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ0sP6/1), but I don't get the specs from these examples. Please **clarify** the rules.

Comment: Any length restrictions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 0-25 characters

Comment: Try [`'~^(?=.{0,25}$)[+#]?\d*(?:X*|\*?)$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ0sP6/2) - this will make sure the whole string is 0 to 25 chars long, and will only allow one `*` at the end of the string, and zero or more `X` can only follow 0 or more digits. **Please check**.

Comment: It looks like this `^[0-9]{0,25}[*]{0,1}$|^[0-9]{0,25}[X]*$` would resolve my problem need to test it though.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew that should work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
'~^(?=.{0,25}$)[+#]?\d*(?:X*|\*?)$~D'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ0sP6/2)

This will make sure the whole string is 0 to 25 chars long, and will only allow one `*` at the end of the string, and zero or more `X` can only follow 0 or more digits.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,25}$)` - a positive lookahead checking the whole string length (must be from 0 to 25 chars long)
- `[+#]?` - one or zero `+` or `#`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:X*|\*?)` - a non-capturing group matching either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `X*` - zero or more `X` symbols
  - `|` - or...
  - `\*?` - one or zero `*` symbols
- `$` - end of string (better replace it with `\z` to ensure no newline at the end is accepted, or just add `D` modifier).

Comment: Please note I used the `D` modifier in the regex, it will make sure the `$` matches the very end of the string. Without it, `$` may match before the final newline symbol which might not be good when validation is performed. Note you can also replace `$` with `\z` anchor to achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your needs, this would do the job:

```
^\d+(?:x+|\*)?$
```

New version according to question edit:

```
^[+#]?\d*(?:x+|\*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new update:

```
^(?=.)[+#*]?\d*?(?:X+|\*)?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO2aT3/4)

Explanation:

```
^           # Asserts beginnig of input string
(?=.)       # Positive looakehad - input string length should be at least 1
[+#*]?      # Optional symbols 
\d*?        # Optional digits (any number)
    (?:         # Start of non-capturing group (a)
        X+          # Any number of X
        |           # Or
        \*          # A single *
    )?          # End of non-capturing group (a) - optional
$           # End of string
```